# PostGIS create table with multiple geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry

I want to create a table with a geometry field in it. e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE ptgeogwgs(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, geog geography(POINT) );
```

In my case, this geometry field can either be a POINT, a LINESTRING or a POLYGON. I couldn't find any examples where that unique column could take three different types. So I guess the type of geometry should be fixed in advance. Nonetheless, is is better to create one table for each geometry type or create multiple columns, one for each geometry type.

Furthermore, if I choose for the second option, are the two empty geometry fields stored as "null" and therefore taking some memory space or doesn't empty fields in PostGIS table take any space?

Comment: If you don't add a POINT type, and keep it generic geography (with no type), does it allow any geometry type to be stored in that column?

Comment: You can use geometry type "geometry" and save all kind of geometries into the same column. However, many client programs have difficulties to deal with such tables. Same applies to tables with multiple geometry colums, but it is not problem free to have a triplet of tables either. You must make a decision and select what kind of problems you want to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a generic *geometry* type `GEOMETRY` (not to be confused with the actual *column data type*!), i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE ptgeogwgs (
  gid  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  geog GEOGRAPHY(GEOMETRY, 4326)
);
```

to let the `geog` column accept all *geometry types*. Note that for `GEOGRAPHY`, if left blank, the CRS will be set to `EPSG:4326` by default.

---

Client applications usually deny the work with a single generic *geometry type* column as well as multiple geometry columns in one table!